# Hive script to concatenate string column, input value and int

Tags: hive, concatenation, hue

How can I concatenate a string columnA, input value "FLOWERS" and YEAR and MONTH from date field which I've tried to convert to string. The script I tried is the below.

```
select concat_ws(columnA, 'FLOWERS', cast(YEAR(from_unixtime(start_date)), varchar()), 
cast(MONTH(from_unixtime(start_date)), varchar()) as concatfield
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

concat(merchant, 'FLOWERS', cast(YEAR(from_unixtime(start_date)) as string), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(from_unixtime(start_date) ,'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MMM'))